# Passing different types to view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a method in controler in which I pass to view objects with different type like:

```
case ItemType.Magnets:  
{
   return View(dbHelper.Magnets.Details(id));
}
case ItemType.Maps:
{
   return View(dbHelper.Maps.Details(id));
}
```

How can I write a view for this?

Comment: If Magnets and Maps are subclasses and inherit from the same Base class, you can make your view for that. Otherwise, I have no idea, I don't think you're supposed to have the same view for different types.

Comment: Are the types returned by `Details(id)` the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to create two different views, each called unique and each accepting its own viewmodel.

You will also want to specify view's name in the controller class:

```
return View("ViewName_1", dbHelper.Maps.Details(id));
```

or

```
return View("ViewName_2", dbHelper.Magnets.Details(id));
```

@AlexDefine unless you want to create a **universal** view for all types of properties inside, which is not that easy.

Part of it I have here:

```
@model object

<table>
    @{
        var properties = from prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties
                         let propInfo = prop.ContainerType.GetProperty(prop.PropertyName)
                         where !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(prop)
                         select prop;
    }

    @foreach (var prop in properties)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="float: right;">
                    @prop.GetDisplayName()
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName, new { ContainerModel = Model })
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

More or less, it makes a table of any kind of model. But you should upgrade it for your needs by self.

Comment: Well I know that, but I am looking for faster way.. In your cases I need to create 12 views for each product type, and that is to much.

Answer (score 1):

You need to creates different views for different item. Here is **solution**

```
case ItemType.Magnets:  
{
  return View("MagnetsView",dbHelper.Magnets.Details(id));
}
case ItemType.Maps:
{
  return View("Maps",dbHelper.Maps.Details(id));
}
```

If you want to display Magnets item you need to create **Magnet view**. Same for Maps.